# I can not get the error "Variable uninitialized" to go away

Tags: c, scanf

Please help me fix this program. I need to know whats missing? its giving me errors on my "scan" and "if" lines. telling me that i have "uninitialized variables? Im really not sure how to correct it!

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
//Local Declarations
int c;
int f;
int cel;
int fah;
int enter;
//Statements

printf("\nThis program converts Celsius temperatire to Fahrenheit degree and Fahrenheit         temperature to Celsius degree.");
printf("\nIf you want to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit, please enter c.");
printf("\nIf you want to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, please enter f.");
scanf("%d, &enter");

if(enter==c)
{
printf("\nEnter Celsius temperature.");
enter=cel;
    scanf("%d", &cel);
fah=cel*5/9 + 32;
printf("%d", fah);
}

if(enter==f)
{
printf("\nEnter Fahrenheit degree.");
    enter=fah;
    scanf("%d", &fah);
cel=(fah-32)*5/9;
printf("%d", cel);
}

return 0;


} //main
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `java`? Is this because you are drinking coffee?

Comment: Take a good look at that first `scanf` call again.

Comment: Then take a good look at the `if` conditions too.

Comment: You need to learn about string and character literals.

Comment: +1 Just because the edit of Eric replaced the whole OP...

Comment: I replaced it to an SSCCE, but people complained, so I rolled it back.  This river of nonsense is about ready to drive me to drinking and leave stackoverflow to morph into yahoo answers.  Pretty soon reputation on stackoverflow isn't going to mean anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End your quotes before comma. Commas give the arguments for your type casted place holder such as %d for integer value.

%d is to take input or print out integer

I think its wrong to solve your assignment, but here you go.

```
    int main (void)
    {
    //Local Declarations
    int cel;
    int fah;
    char enter;
    //Statements

    printf("Gerald Onesky COP2220 Project 3");
    printf("\nThis program converts Celsius temperatire to Fahrenheit degree and Fahrenheit  temperature to Celsius degree.");
    printf("\nIf you want to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit, please enter c.");
    printf("\nIf you want to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, please enter f.");
    scanf("%c, &enter");

    if(enter=='c')
    {
        printf("\nEnter Celsius temperature.");        
        scanf("%d", &cel);
        fah=cel*5/9 + 32;
        printf("Celsius temperature is %d and Fahrenheit temperature is %d", cel, fah);
    }

    if(enter=='f')
    {
        printf("\nEnter Fahrenheit degree.");
        scanf("%d", &fah);
        cel=(fah-32)*5/9;
        printf("Celsius temperature is %d and Fahrenheit temperature is %d", cel, fah);
    }    
    return 0;   
  } //main
```

Comment: I am just starting out learning this and really appreciate the input. I really just wanted the errors to go away and to see why i am getting them in the first place. The program still isn't right but the answers i received were perfect. i will use the text to figure out why.

Comment: did the code above compiled for you well?

Comment: Yes thanks, it compiled after corrections. just need a lot of specifics added.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
printf("\nIf you want to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit, please enter c.");
printf("\nIf you want to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, please enter f.");
printf("\nIf you want to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, please enter f.");
scanf("%d, &enter");
```

to

```
printf("\nIf you want to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit, please enter c.");
scanf("%d", &c);
printf("\nIf you want to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, please enter f.");
scanf("%d", &f);
printf("\nIf you want to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius, please enter f.");
scanf("%d", &enter);
```

In `if(enter==f)`, `f` is not initialized.
(This code has too many errors!!)

Answer (score 2):

What are the variables `c` and `f` used for?  You use them in comparisons, but you never assign anything to them.

Based on the logic of your code, I'm assuming you want to check if the user entered the *characters* `'c'` or `'f'`.  If that's the case, you will want to make the following changes:

```
char enter;
...
scanf(" %c", &enter); // leading space in format string is important; %c won't skip
                      // leading whitespace by itself, so if you don't want to 
                      // accidentally capture a newline or other whitespace character,
                      // you need to have the leading space before the conversion
                      // specifier.
...
if (enter == 'c')     // compare enter to the *value* 'c', not the variable c
  // process celcius

if (enter == 'f')     // same as above, but for 'f'
  // process fahrenheit
```

Comment: Your explanations helped a lot i have a lot to learn and appreciate all the input.